# Offline grub-efi installation (Offline BIOS Legacy to UEFI conversion)

Tags: grub2, package-management, root, grub-efi, offline

I need to convert from BIOS Legacy to UEFI on a Linux Ubuntu computer **without reinstalling Linux** itself and **without the Internet**.
I have managed to do it with the Internet, but it seems to be very problematic without it (I do have another PC with the Internet connection, though).

I have got to the point, where I delete `grub-pc` for Legacy. After that I am stuck. I cannot install `grub-efi`.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Get a LiveUSB with Ubuntu (it is complicated. Even though I have Linux installed, there's nothing in it, so I have to use a LiveUSB. That is not the issue xD).
2. Created an EFI Partition, formatted it as fat32, set the boot and esp flags. (with GParted)
3. Mounted my partitions:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot/efi
$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$ mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
```

4. checked my fstab, my EFI partition is there:

`$ ls -lh /dev/disk/by-uuid      # UUID=AA93-B9F4 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1`

Now, I am starting to have problems.

5. On my online PC I have downloaded the grub-efi-amd64 with all the dependencies, like this:

```
$ apt-get download $(apt-rdepends grub-efi-amd64 | grep -v "^ " | sed 's/debconf-2.0/debconf/g')
```

...and copied them to a USB.

6. I removed the old GRUB:

`$ sudo apt-get purge grub-pc`

7. Copied the packaged to the offline computer, changed the directory to where I copied them and installed them with

$ `sudo dpkg -i *`

And that is it. Nothing happens. The packages seem to get installed just fine, and my ubuntu is even being shown in the efibootmgr, but as soon as I restart the computer, I don't have the option. It doesn't work and I don't know how to install those packages as root (I am, apparently, supposed to `$sudo chroot /mnt` and then install grub) and if it matters at all.

I am a very much noob in Linux, so I will be glad any help :c

Thanks,
Larysa

Comment: Did you change UEFI settings from Legacy/BIOS/CSM to UEFI boot mode? What brand/model system? Some need settings. Also many need UEFI update. Most systems let you download update file and install from FAT32 partition directly from within UEFI.

Comment: Hey, I have already managed to change from Legacy to UEFI and back on this machine, so everzthing is fine with the UEFI itself. But then I had an Internet connection. Now I need to figure out how to do it completely offline.

Comment: If you have # in front to the mount to the ESP, it is commented out. Reinstall of grub in BIOS/CSM mode does that. Boot-Repair comments out original line and adds its own with different parameters to make it easier to edit files in ESP.